# Is there a way for use UserName instead of email in Password Reset flow in Azure AD B2C?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I'm customizing the **PasswordReset** flow in azure ad b2c using custom policies, but i can't find a way for use **UserName** instead **Email** for restore password. I've tried to use input **signInName** instead of email in the technical profile **AAD-UserReadUsingEmailAddress**, but still shows the email in the form.

```
<TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-UserReadUsingEmailAddress">
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="Operation">Read</Item>
            <Item Key="RaiseErrorIfClaimsPrincipalDoesNotExist">true</Item>
            <Item Key="UserMessageIfClaimsPrincipalDoesNotExist">An account could not be found for the provided user ID.</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <IncludeInSso>false</IncludeInSso>
          <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" PartnerClaimType="signInNames.userName" Required="true" />
          </InputClaims>
          <OutputClaims>
            <!-- Required claims -->
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" DefaultValue="localAccountAuthentication" />
  
            <!-- Optional claims -->
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="userPrincipalName" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="accountEnabled" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="otherMails" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInNames.emailAddress" />
          </OutputClaims>
          <OutputClaimsTransformations>
            <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="AssertAccountEnabledIsTrue" />
          </OutputClaimsTransformations>
          <IncludeTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-Common" />
        </TechnicalProfile>
```

It's possible to do this with userName?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This technical profile is the implementation to READ the account. What you are trying to achieve is to show the Username text box first and foremost. To display something on screen, you need to modify a **selfAsserted** technical profile.

The key is to change the operating mode to [Username](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/blob/master/policies/username-signup-or-signin/policy/Username_TrustFrameworkExtensions.xml#L190) in the selfAsserted technical profile which asks the user for their identifer (which from the starter pack is: `LocalAccountDiscoveryUsingEmailAddress`), the latest key name is `setting.operatingMode`, reference [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/self-asserted-technical-profile#metadata), set it to `username`. Then the textbox validation will be for username.

There is a complete sample [here](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/username-signup-or-signin), and you can quick deploy using this [link](https://b2ciefsetupapp.azurewebsites.net/Home/Experimental?sampleFolderName=username-signup-or-signin).

Comment: I've tried this, and appears username input in the form, but keep appearing email input, is there a way for reset password with just username?

Comment: You can, but without verifying the associated email, that would be a security hole.

Comment: Do you know a way for get the email associated to the username and send the code?

Comment: That’s a good idea. Yes it’s possible but more involved, I can make a sample for that.

Comment: Really? that would be great!